# Why would line-spacing change for the last line in a paragraph when using reledmac?

Tags: line-spacing, polyglossia, line-numbering, reledmac

MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{book}

\usepackage[nolocalmarks]{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage[variant=medieval]{latin}

\usepackage[noend,nofamiliar,noledgroup,series={A}]{reledmac}
\Xlemmaseparator[A]{:}

\begin{document}

\beginnumbering
\pstart
\begin{latin}
\textenglish{\textbf{6.}} In sexta denique, intellectio ab imaginatione secernitur; distinctionum signa describuntur; mentem realiter a corpore distingui probatur; eandem nihilominus tam arcte illi esse coniunctam, ut unum quid cum ipsa componat, ostenditur; omnes errores qui a sensibus oriri solent recensentur; modi quibus vitari possint exponuntur; et denique rationes omnes ex quibus rerum materialium existentia possit concludi, afferuntur: non quod eas valde utiles esse putarim ad probandum id ipsum quod probant, nempe revera esse aliquem mundum, et homines habere corpora, et similia, de quibus nemo unquam sanae mentis serio dubitavit; sed quia, illas considerando, agnoscitur non esse tam firmas nec tam perspicuas quam sunt eae, per quas in mentis nostrae et Dei cognitionem devenimus; adeo ut hae sint omnium certissimae et evidentissimae quae ab humano ingenio sciri possint. Cuius unius rei probationem in his Meditationibus mihi pro scopo proposui. Nec idcirco hic recenseo varias illas quaestiones de quibus etiam in ipsis ex occasione tractatur.

\end{latin}
\pend
\endnumbering

\textenglish{\textbf{6.}} In sexta denique, intellectio ab imaginatione secernitur; distinctionum signa describuntur; mentem realiter a corpore distingui probatur; eandem nihilominus tam arcte illi esse coniunctam, ut unum quid cum ipsa componat, ostenditur; omnes errores qui a sensibus oriri solent recensentur; modi quibus vitari possint exponuntur; et denique rationes omnes ex quibus rerum materialium existentia possit concludi, afferuntur: non quod eas valde utiles esse putarim ad probandum id ipsum quod probant, nempe revera esse aliquem mundum, et homines habere corpora, et similia, de quibus nemo unquam sanae mentis serio dubitavit; sed quia, illas considerando, agnoscitur non esse tam firmas nec tam perspicuas quam sunt eae, per quas in mentis nostrae et Dei cognitionem devenimus; adeo ut hae sint omnium certissimae et evidentissimae quae ab humano ingenio sciri possint. Cuius unius rei probationem in his Meditationibus mihi pro scopo proposui. Nec idcirco hic recenseo varias illas quaestiones de quibus etiam in ipsis ex occasione tractatur.

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image: Squeezed final line]

When I use [reledmac](http://ctan.org/pkg/reledmac) to add line numbers (see note below), the final line of paragraphs is often "squeezed" in this way. (And sometimes, equally randomly, there will be an extra space added between two paragraphs. But let's focus on one problem at a time, I suppose.) As you can see in the image, if I don't use reledmac on the same text, the problem goes away.

A quick follow-up: if I remove [polyglossia](http://ctan.org/pkg/polyglossia), the problem disappears. So perhaps it's an interaction of polyglossia and reledmac?

Any suggestions for how to address this would be welcome.

**NB**: I don't actually use reledmac just for line numbers. I also use it to create a [critical apparatus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_apparatus), but I've trimmed this example down to the minimum needed to show the problem. I mention this only in case someone suggests dumping reledmac in favor of something else that only does line numbering.

Comment: you could remove `\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Baskerville}` as the font isn't generally available (and the problem shows without)

Comment: removing the blank line before `\end{latin}` fixes the bad line but makes the vertical gap go (and reformats all the first para....)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I removed the unnecessary bits. The blank line appears to be the problem. I think I'm careless sometimes about blank lines before such breaks.

Comment: I suspect reledmac could detect that and at least warn, but if that's OK as an answer i could post it as such:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Feel free to post it as an answer, and I'll accept it. I'll add my own answer later, once I figure out a few other things about the placement of `\begin{language}` and `\end{language}`. The problem seems to be polyglossia not reledmac as I originally thought.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing the blank line before `\end{latin}` fixes the bad line but also makes the vertical gap before the next paragraph go (I'm not sure if that gap is intended)

Comment: The gap wasn't intended. It turns out that I should be placing `\begin{language}` and `\end{language}` more carefully. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I initially assumed that the [reledmac](http://ctan.org/pkg/reledmac) was to blame, but the real problem was my careless use of [polyglossia](http://ctan.org/pkg/polyglossia).

First, I was carelessly leaving blank lines sometimes before `\end{latin}`. Second, I was placing `\begin{latin}` and `\end{latin}` further out than I needed.

In a nutshell, I was doing this:

```
\beginnumbering
\pstart
\begin{latin}
\textenglish{\textbf{6.}} In sexta denique, intellectio ab imaginatione (etc.)

\end{latin}
\pend
\endnumbering
```

But I should do this:

```
\beginnumbering
\pstart
\textbf{6.} \begin{latin}In sexta denique, intellectio ab imaginatione (etc.)\end{latin}
\pend
\endnumbering
```

By doing that, I cleared up *all* the line-spacing issues I was having, both the final lines occasionally being squeezed too tight and the occasional extra spaces between paragraphs.

I'm not sure if polyglossia should be more forgiving about this sort of thing or not, but I'm happy enough to have things fixed.